# Twilio <Gather> not picking up spoken letters

Tags: .net-core, twilio, twilio-twiml

I've created a .NET Core API that my Twilio number connects to. It's all working great apart from one part where I ask the user to speak an Id. This is made up of letters and numbers e.g. "A123456". I am consistently having the first letter missed, especially when it's an 'a'.

The `<Gather>` I have is:-

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
var gather = new Gather(action: new Uri("/Voice/RepeatId", UriKind.Relative),
    language: _language,
    method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get, 
    speechModel: Gather.SpeechModelEnum.PhoneCall, 
    input: new List<Gather.InputEnum>() {Gather.InputEnum.Speech},
    timeout: 3, hints: BatchIdHint);
gather
    .Say("Please say the I D.", _voice,
        language: _language);
response.Append(gather);
response.Say("I'm sorry, I did not hear you. Please try again.", _voice, language: _language);
response.Redirect(
    method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
    url: new Uri("/Voice/EnterId", UriKind.Relative));

return TwiML(response);
```

I've confirmed, using `ngrok` to run the code locally, that the SpeechResult sent to the RepeatId is missing the first letter.

I found something in the Twilio docs about using 'enhanced' with the PhoneCall speechModel, but that property does not seem available to set on my `<Gather>`.

Is there anything I can do to improve the system picking up that first letter?

Answer (score 0):

In hints (of you Gather Input on Call Widget) , you can enter a meta-hint, `$OOV_CLASS_ALPHANUMERIC_SEQUENCE`. It will help but speech collection is inherently challenging.

Another option is to have a post-processing function to help normalize the collected input, `SpeechResult` based on valid account number criteria, and reading the normalized result back to the customer.